# Проблема с angular или npm? Не стартует проект

Tags: linux, node.js, angular2, npm, manjaro

Делаю согласно [букваря](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0):

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Проходит без проблем.

```
ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
```

Проект тоже собирается без ошибок, но при выполнении:

```
ng serve --open
```

вываливается куча ошибок:

```
$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-03-22T21:34:11.543Z                                                     
Hash: 990b3212bea3695a86e3
Time: 2443ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 494 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 293 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 282 bytes [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-of-heroes'
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-of-heroes'
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-of-heroes'
ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-of-heroes'
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-  of-heroes':
  Error: Can't resolve '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/' in '/media/Soft/рабстол/programming/!angular2/heros/angular-tour-of-heroes'

  - compiler.js:76 
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:300 compile
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:300:11

  - Compiler.js:510 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:510:14

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - CachePlugin.js:78 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:507 compilation.seal.err
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:507:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:677 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:677:19

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:668 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:668:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:663 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:663:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:659 applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:659:9

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [angular-tour-of-heroes]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46



webpack: Failed to compile.
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Может пакета какого не хватает?

ОС linux Manjaro 17.1.6 Hakoila

ПС npm переустанавливал, nodejs тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в наличии восклицательного знака в имени каталога, этого - '!'.